# Why is this not sufficient proof of the divisibility of $\binom{p}{j}$ by $p$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation, prime-factorization

In my text book there's an example of a proof on why $\binom{p}{j}$ is divisible by $p$, with $p$ prime, for $0<j<p$. Firstly, it shows that

$$\binom{p}{j}=p\frac{(p-1)!}{j!(p-j)!}$$

From this it also points out that we know $p-1, j, p-j$ are all less than $p$, and therefore $p$ is not in the prime factorization of neither of them. Then it says (I quote): "*Now, from the identity of equation 26...*" (the one written above) "*$p$ must be a factor of $\binom{p}{j}$*".

Two correlated doubts: why do we need to note that $p$ does not appear in the prime factorization of $j$, $p-1$ and $p-$j? And why is it not enough to show that $\binom{p}{j}=pk$, as it is shown on the equation, to demonstrate that $\binom{p}{j}$ is divisible by $p$?

Comment: We could write $2=4\times\frac12$, but that does not mean $2$ is divisible by $4$

Comment: We need $p\nmid j!$ and $p\nmid(p-j)!$, not just $p\nmid j$ and $p\nmid(p-j)$.

Comment: General theory on binomials yields that $\frac{p!}{j!(p-j)!}$ is an integer, but you are not necessarily guaranteed that $\frac{(p-1)!}{j!(p-j)!}$ is an integer.